# How to change Amplify backend in local Flutter project

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

I have an Flutter project which is using Amazon Amplify resources.

My problem is that I have two Amplify solutions ( seperate appId, not just dev/prod environments ) that I'm using with my Flutter application.

Whenever I try to switch the Amplify files in local with : amplify pull --appId  --envName dev.

I receive the error:
Amplify appId mismatch.
You are currently working in the amplify project with Id

Is there a way to switch appId's without deleting the Amplify CLI and installing it again?

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed that when you go to the Backend environment of the app in Amplify it shows you:

```
amplify pull --appId ######### --envName dev
```

With the #'s as the id of the app. After that, you use:

```
amplify init
```

And this should allow you to select the new environment of the app.